# image will not scale to 100% of div properly?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to make the image take up the whole page for my component but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong?

this is how it currently looks and I cannot figure out how to ensure it takes up the extra whitespace marked in red too.

I tried setting the min width and height of the div it is contained in. Is it maybe I need to set the image up in the body but I was confused how to do that in react.

current page: [image]

css:

```
.container {
    background-image: url("../images/img.jpg");

        
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
}

.default-button {
    align-items: center;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #fa6400;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0 1px 3px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-family: "Rams Black";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 1.25;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 3rem;
    padding: calc(.875rem - 1px) calc(1.5rem - 1px);
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 250ms;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: auto;
}

.default-button:hover,
.default-button:focus {
    background-color: #fb8332;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 4px 12px;
}

.default-button:hover {
    transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.default-button:active {
    background-color: #c85000;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .06) 0 2px 4px;
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.powered-by-strava {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.connect-btn {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
```

component where image is rendered:

```
 return (
    <div className="container">
      
        <button className="connect-btn" onClick={stravaAuth}><img src={connectSVG}
        alt="Connect to Strava"/></button>
        <button onClick={changeTheme}>Change mode</button>
        <div className="powered-by-strava">
          <img className="strava-img" src={poweredSVG}/>
        </div>
      
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Do you want the image to cover the whole page or do you want it to cover the viewport (the part the user can see at any one time - normally the screen on a mobile phone).

Comment: @AHaworth the whole page so from top to the bottom of the white section

Comment: @CornelRaiu that does not fix the issue

Comment: I’m surprised using cover doesn’t fix it, the background should cover the whole of the container. Could you therefore create a runnable snippet so we can see for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I managed to sort it by setting body height to 100vh and then the container also to 100vh